# Overlap issue with tables using FPDF library

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm working on a PHP web project using FPDF library, which is working fine. My ongoing task is to insert a table in the generated pdf page. Since I need to output the table in a specific way (see picture below), it is being very difficult to use the existing scripts one can find here : http://www.fpdf.org/fr/script/index.php. I'm using the classes provided in the link as traits in my custom PDF class.

My MySQL table:
[image]

The specific way of rendering data:
[image]

colonne (French) = column (English) / ligne = line

- With "Tables HTML" script (written by Azeem Abbas, see http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script70.php), I've been able to output the table in right way (see picture below), but could not manage to handle margins, width and other html properties.
  [image]
- With "Table with MySQL" script (written by Olivier, see http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script14.php), no way to ouput data the exact way I did it with "Tables HTML" script. I've tried to rewrite Table and Row function, but could get good result.
- In both cases I encounter text overlap issue whenener I have quite long text in cells. I tried MultiCell function, it causing cells to pile up.

[image]

Here is the code i'm using:

Any ideas about a library that can help me get a html table inside pdf page with overlap issue and the possibility to change table html properties?

***Update: Oct 10, 2019***
I've just found answer to the overlap issue in the code below written by Olivier (http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php):

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF_MC_Table extends FPDF
{
var $widths;
var $aligns;

function SetWidths($w)
{
    //Set the array of column widths
    $this->widths=$w;
}

function SetAligns($a)
{
    //Set the array of column alignments
    $this->aligns=$a;
}

function Row($data)
{
    //Calculate the height of the row
    $nb=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
        $nb=max($nb,$this->NbLines($this->widths[$i],$data[$i]));
    $h=5*$nb;
    //Issue a page break first if needed
    $this->CheckPageBreak($h);
    //Draw the cells of the row
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    {
        $w=$this->widths[$i];
        $a=isset($this->aligns[$i]) ? $this->aligns[$i] : 'L';
        //Save the current position
        $x=$this->GetX();
        $y=$this->GetY();
        //Draw the border
        $this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h);
        //Print the text
        $this->MultiCell($w,5,$data[$i],0,$a);
        //Put the position to the right of the cell
        $this->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
    }
    //Go to the next line
    $this->Ln($h);
}

function CheckPageBreak($h)
{
    //If the height h would cause an overflow, add a new page immediately
    if($this->GetY()+$h>$this->PageBreakTrigger)
        $this->AddPage($this->CurOrientation);
}

function NbLines($w,$txt)
{
    //Computes the number of lines a MultiCell of width w will take
    $cw=&$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    if($w==0)
        $w=$this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
    $wmax=($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize;
    $s=str_replace("\r",'',$txt);
    $nb=strlen($s);
    if($nb>0 and $s[$nb-1]=="\n")
        $nb--;
    $sep=-1;
    $i=0;
    $j=0;
    $l=0;
    $nl=1;
    while($i<$nb)
    {
        $c=$s[$i];
        if($c=="\n")
        {
            $i++;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
            continue;
        }
        if($c==' ')
            $sep=$i;
        $l+=$cw[$c];
        if($l>$wmax)
        {
            if($sep==-1)
            {
                if($i==$j)
                    $i++;
            }
            else
                $i=$sep+1;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
        }
        else
            $i++;
    }
    return $nl;
}
}
?>
```

Now the only problem I have is editing `Row()` function in the above code so the table is rendered in the specific way I mentioned.

This is how `Row()` function is used as stated in the documentation of the above class (see http://www.fpdf.org/fr/script/script3.php):

```
function GenerateWord()
{
    //Get a random word
    $nb=rand(3,10);
    $w='';
    for($i=1;$i<=$nb;$i++)
        $w.=chr(rand(ord('a'),ord('z')));
    return $w;
}

function GenerateSentence()
{
    //Get a random sentence
    $nb=rand(1,10);
    $s='';
    for($i=1;$i<=$nb;$i++)
        $s.=GenerateWord().' ';
    return substr($s,0,-1);
}

$pdf=new PDF_MC_Table();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
//Table with 20 rows and 4 columns
$pdf->SetWidths(array(30,50,30,40));
srand(microtime()*1000000);
for($i=0;$i<20;$i++)
    $pdf->Row(array(GenerateSentence(),GenerateSentence(),GenerateSentence(),GenerateSentence()));
$pdf->Output();
```

In my case the array to pass on to Row function is a tridimensional one:

```
$table =
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => colonne1 ligne1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [4] => colonne2   ligne1  
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [9] => colonne3 ligne1 

                )

        )

    [pos_paragr_prec] => 0
    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2] => colonne1 ligne2  
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [7] => colonne2 ligne2 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [10] => colonne3 ligne2  
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [3] => colonne1 ligne3 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [8] => colonne2 ligne3
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [11] => colonne3 ligne3
                )

        )

)
```

Any hints on how the Row function can be edited to produce the table in the way mentioned above?

So far, I've tried to do something like this without editing the Row function:

```
if (count($table) > 0) {
        foreach($table as $row_array) {
            foreach($row_array as $key => $val) {
                for($i=0;$i<count($row_array);$i++) {
                    $pdf->Row($val);
                }                                       
            }
        }
    }
```

This, obviously, doesn't work.

**Update**

I have made some improvements in my code this way:

```
if (count($table) > 0) {

    if (is_array($table_data) && count($table_data) > 0) {
        foreach ($table_data as $key => $value) {
            $arrayWidths = [];                          

            foreach($value as $key2 => $val) {

                array_push($arrayWidths, 40);
                $pdf->SetWidths($arrayWidths);

                foreach($val as $k => $col) {

                    $w=40;//$pdf->widths[$key2];
                    $a='L';//isset($pdf->aligns[$i]) ? $pdf->aligns[$key2] : 'L';
                    //Save current position 
                    $x=$pdf->GetX();
                    $y=$pdf->GetY();
                    //Drawing the border
                    $pdf->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h);
                    //Printing text
                    $pdf->MultiCell($w,5,$table_data[$key][$key2][$k],0,$a);
                    //Putting the position to the right of the cell
                    $pdf->SetXY($x+$w,$y);                      

                }                               

            }
            $pdf->Ln();                         
        }

    }

}
```

By now data are being rendered the specific way I wanted. However, there is a difference between the first row and the rest. The first row is acceptable. I have the overlap issue with those rows below the first one. Here is the result that I've got:

[image]

I used the logic of this script : http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php (see the code pasted above).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include your code so please [edit] your question and include the code that has the problem. A small data sample, if needed, would be helpful too.

Comment: @Dave, Thanks for your reply, I've edited my post. I didn't put the code since I'm using the exact code accessible here: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script14.php and http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script70.php

Comment: @Dave I've just edited my post to include the progress that I've made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to produce a table the right way by rewriting the code available here, so it fits the specificity of my context:  fpdf.org/en/script/script14.php. Below is what I did.

1. I created the following trait, which I used inside PDF class :

   ```
   <?php

   trait PDF_SQL_Table
   {
   protected $aCols=array();
   protected $TableX;
   protected $HeaderColor;
   protected $RowColors;
   protected $ColorIndex;

   /**
    * @return void
    */
   function TableHeader()
   {
       $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
       $this->SetTextColor(0); ## Couleur de police de caractères de l'en-tête du tableau

       ## Couleur de fond de l'en-tête du tableau
       $fill=!empty($this->HeaderColor);
       if($fill)
           $this->SetFillColor($this->HeaderColor[0],$this->HeaderColor[1],$this->HeaderColor[2]);
   }

   /**
    * @param array $tableData
    * @param $width
    * @param $align
    * @param $TableWidth
    * @param $key
    * @return float|int
    */
   function CalcWidths(array $tableData, $width, $align, $TableWidth, $key)
   {
       $w = $this->aCols[$key]['w'];
       if($w==-1)
           $w = $width/count($tableData);
       elseif(substr($w,-1) == '%')
           $w = $w/100 * $width;
       $this->aCols[$key]['w'] = $w;
       $TableWidth += $w;

       // Calcul de l'abscisse du tableau
       if($align=='C')
           $this->TableX=max(($this->w-$TableWidth)/2,0);
       elseif($align=='R')
           $this->TableX= $this->TableX=max($this->w-$this->rMargin-$TableWidth,0);//max($this->w-15-$TableWidth,0); //$this->TableX=max($this->w-$this->rMargin-$TableWidth,0);
       else
           $this->TableX=$this->lMargin;//15; // $this->TableX=$this->lMargin;

       return $w;
   }

   /**
    * @param int $field
    * @param int $width
    * @param string $caption
    * @param string $align
    */
   function AddCol($field=-1, $width=-1, $caption='', $align='L'): void
   {
       // Ajout d'une colonne du tableau
       if($field == -1)
           $field = count($this->aCols);
       $this->aCols[$field]=array('f'=>$field,'c'=>$caption,'w'=>$width,'a'=>$align);
   }

   /**
    * @param array $table
    * @param array $prop
    * @param array $array_paragraphes
    * @param float $interligne
    * @param array $excludedParagraphs
    * @param $dec
    */
   function TableAndParagraphs(array $table = array(), array $prop=array(), array $array_paragraphes, float $interligne, array $excludedParagraphs, $dec): void
   {
       foreach ($array_paragraphes as $ordre => $paragraphe) {
           ### $this->Ln(10); En activant ceci à cet endroit précis, un des tableaux s'affiche sur plusieurs pages de façon discontinue
           ###  Insertion d'un tableau au dessous du paragraphe correspondant à ordre_texte_saisi = $table['pos_paragr_prec']
           ### Utilisation d'une extension de la librairie FPDF disponible ici (que nous avons personnalisée) : http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=14

           $counter = 0;
           foreach ($table as $num_tableau => $donnees_tableau) {
               ## Insertion d'un tableau au dessous du paragraphe correspondant à ordre_texte_saisi = $table['pos_paragr_prec']
               ## Utilisation d'une extension de la librairie FPDF disponible ici : http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=14
               // Gestion des propriétés
               if(!isset($prop['width']))
                   $prop['width']=0;
               if($prop['width']==0)
                   $prop['width']= $this->w-$this->lMargin-$this->rMargin;//$this->w-15-15; //($this->lMargin = 15 / $this->rMargin = 15  cf. plus haut)
               if(!isset($prop['align']))
                   $prop['align']='C';
               if(!isset($prop['padding']))
                   $prop['padding']=$this->cMargin;
               $cMargin=$this->cMargin;
               $this->cMargin=$prop['padding'];
               if(!isset($prop['HeaderColor']))
                   $prop['HeaderColor']=array();
               $this->HeaderColor=$prop['HeaderColor'];
               if(!isset($prop['color1']))
                   $prop['color1']=array();
               if(!isset($prop['color2']))
                   $prop['color2']=array();
               $this->RowColors=array($prop['color1'],$prop['color2']);

               $this->ColorIndex = 0;

               if ($ordre === ($table[$num_tableau]['pos_paragr_prec'])) {
                   $excludedParagraphs[] = $ordre;
                   ### $this->Ln(10); En activant ceci un des tableaux s'affiche sur plusieurs pages de façon discontinue
                   $paragraphe = html_entity_decode($paragraphe, ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8");
                   $this->MultiCell(0,$interligne,$paragraphe);
                   ### $this->Ln($dec);  En activant ceci, à partir de la 2ème ligne du tableau l'affichage se fait sur plusieurs pages avec une cellule par page

                   if (count($table) > 0) {
                       $this->Ln(10); ### Un espace vertical avant d'afficher le tableau
                       if (is_array($donnees_tableau) && count($donnees_tableau) > 0) {

                           $iteration = 0; ### indice d'itération sur les tableaux
                           $TableWidth=0;
                           foreach ($donnees_tableau as $key => $value) { ### Début d'affichage d'un tableau

                               ### Si la hauteur h = 20 provoque un débordement, on effectue un saut de page manuel
                               ### $this->Ln(0);  juste un test : activer ceci donne une idée sur le traitement ligne par ligne (ceci produit une nette séparation entre les lignes)

                               $this->CheckPageBreak(10);// ceci permet de pouvoir afficher un tableau sur 2 ou plusieurs pages
                               $this->SetX(15);// On décale le tableau vers la droite de 18 unités (en argument de la fonction SetX()). Permet de déplacer le tableau horizontalement

                               $number = 0; // Itération sur les données du tableau

                               foreach($value as $key2 => $val) {

                                   foreach($val as $k => $col) {
                                       // Ajout dynamique d'une colonne au tableau
                                       $this->AddCol($key2, -1, '', 'R');
                                       // Calcul dynamique de la largeur de la colonne
                                       $w = $this->CalcWidths($value, $prop['width'], 'L', $TableWidth, $key2);

                                       $ci = $this->ColorIndex;
                                       $fill=!empty($this->RowColors[$ci]);
                                       if($fill)
                                           $this->SetFillColor($this->RowColors[$ci][0],$this->RowColors[$ci][1],$this->RowColors[$ci][2]);

                                       $this->SetFont('Arial','',9); // Police de caractère pour les tableaux

                                       if (is_numeric($donnees_tableau[$key][$key2][$k])) {
                                           $cellData = number_format($donnees_tableau[$key][$key2][$k], 2, ',',' ');
                                           $alignRight = true;
                                       } elseif (substr($donnees_tableau[$key][$key2][$k], -1) == '%') {
                                           $cellData = number_format($donnees_tableau[$key][$key2][$k], 2, ',',' ').'%';
                                           $alignRight = true;
                                       } elseif (preg_match('/^[0-9+-]{1,3}(\s|,)[0-9]{1,3}\s?[0-9]{0,3},?[0-9]{0,2}/', $donnees_tableau[$key][$key2][$k])) {
                                           $cellData = $donnees_tableau[$key][$key2][$k];
                                           $alignRight = true;
                                       } elseif (preg_match('/[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{0,2}/', $donnees_tableau[$key][$key2][$k])) {
                                           $cellData = str_replace(',', ' ', $donnees_tableau[$key][$key2][$k]);
                                           $cellData = str_replace('.', ',', $cellData);
                                           $alignRight = true;
                                       } elseif (preg_match('/^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{2,4})$/', $donnees_tableau[$key][$key2][$k])) {
                                           //$cellData = preg_replace('/^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{2,4})$/', "$2/$1/$3", $donnees_tableau[$key][$key2][$k]);
                                           $cellData = date_create($donnees_tableau[$key][$key2][$k]);
                                           $cellData = date_format($cellData, "d/m/Y");
                                           $alignRight = false;
                                       } else {
                                           $cellData = $donnees_tableau[$key][$key2][$k];
                                           $alignRight = false;
                                       }

                                       $x=$this->GetX();
                                       $y=$this->GetY();

                                       ## On évite qu'il y ait des Multicells de hauteur inférieure à celle du Cell suivant sur la même ligne
                                       if ($this->GetStringWidth($donnees_tableau[$key][$key2][$k]) < $w && $key2 == '0' /*&& $key >= '1'*/) {
                                           $spaces = "\n"." "; // Espace insécable : "&#160;"
                                           $cellData .= $spaces;
                                       }

                                       ## Mise en forme du header (police de caractère et couleur de l'arrière-plan)
                                       if ($key == '0') {
                                           $this->TableHeader();
                                       } else {
                                           $this->SetTextColor(0);
                                       }


                                       $this->SetDrawColor(0); ### couleur de la bordure des cellule du tableau : valeur de 0 (noir) à 255 (blanc)
                                       if ($this->GetStringWidth($donnees_tableau[$key][$key2][$k]) > $w || $key2 === 'A' || $key2 == '0') {
                                           $this->MultiCell($w,5,$cellData,1,'L',$fill);
                                           $newY = $this->GetY();
                                           $this->SetXY($x + $w, $y);
                                       } else {
                                           $H = $newY - $y;
                                           if ($alignRight) {
                                               $this->Cell($w, $H,$cellData,1,1,'R',$fill);
                                           } else {
                                               $this->Cell($w, $H,$cellData,1,1,'C',$fill);
                                           }
                                       }

                                       $this->SetFont('Arial','',11);
                                       $this->SetDrawColor(0);
                                       $this->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
                                   }
                                   $number++;
                               }// affichage d'une ligne entière

                               if ($iteration == 1) {
                                   $this->Ln(0); ###### 3 : valeur représentant l'écart entre le header du tableau et le corps du tableau
                               } else {
                                   $this->Ln($H);
                               }

                               // Retour à la ligne afin d'afficher la ligne suivante du tableau
                               $this->ColorIndex = 1-$ci;

                               $iteration++;

                           }// Un tableau entier est affiché

                       }
                   }
               }//if ($ordre === ($table[$num_tableau]['pos_paragr_prec']))

               //Espace entre le premier tableau et le paragraphe en dessous
               if ($counter == 0) {
                   $this->Ln(5.5);
               }

               //Empêcher qu'un paragraphe ne s'affiche plusieurs fois
               if ($counter == count($table) - 1) {

                   //Les paragraphes liés à des tableaux ont été déjà affichés
                   if (!in_array($ordre, $excludedParagraphs)) {
                       $this->Ln(5.5);// Espace entre un tableau et le paragraphe en dessous (premier tableau exclus)
                       $paragraphe = html_entity_decode($paragraphe, ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8");
                       $this->MultiCell(0,$interligne,$paragraphe);
                       $this->Ln($dec);
                   }
               }

               $counter++;
           }
       }
   }
   }
   ```
2. PDF class:

   ```
   class PDF extends TFPDF
   {
       protected $B = 0;
       protected $I = 0;
       protected $U = 0;
       protected $HREF = '';

       use PDF_MC_Table, PDF_SQL_Table;

       function Entete() {

       }

       function Footer() {
          //some code
       }

       //etc.

   }
   ```
3. In the controller, I could call TableAndParagraphs() function this way:

   ```
   $pdf->TableAndParagraphs($table, $prop, $array_paragraphes, $interligne, $excludedParagraphs, $dec);
   ```

   Note that TFPDF is a library based on FPDF (it can be found on Internet):

   ```
   <?php
   /*******************************************************************************
   * tFPDF (based on FPDF 1.7)                                                    *
   *                                                                              *
   * Version:  1.24                                                               *
   * Date:     2011-09-24                                                         *
   * Author:   Ian Back <ianb@bpm1.com>                                           *
   * License:  LGPL                                                               *
   *******************************************************************************/

   define('tFPDF_VERSION','1.24');

   class tFPDF
   {

   var $unifontSubset;
   var $page;               // current page number
   var $n;                  // current object number
   var $offsets;            // array of object offsets
   var $buffer;             // buffer holding in-memory PDF
   var $pages;              // array containing pages
   var $state;              // current document state
   var $compress;           // compression flag
   var $k;                  // scale factor (number of points in user unit)
   var $DefOrientation;     // default orientation
   var $CurOrientation;     // current orientation
   var $StdPageSizes;       // standard page sizes
   var $DefPageSize;        // default page size
   var $CurPageSize;        // current page size
   var $PageSizes;          // used for pages with non default sizes or orientations
   var $wPt, $hPt;          // dimensions of current page in points
   var $w, $h;              // dimensions of current page in user unit
   var $lMargin;            // left margin
   var $tMargin;            // top margin
   var $rMargin;            // right margin
   var $bMargin;            // page break margin
   var $cMargin;            // cell margin
   var $x, $y;              // current position in user unit
   var $lasth;              // height of last printed cell
   var $LineWidth;          // line width in user unit
   var $fontpath;           // path containing fonts
   var $CoreFonts;          // array of core font names
   var $fonts;              // array of used fonts
   var $FontFiles;          // array of font files
   var $diffs;              // array of encoding differences
   var $FontFamily;         // current font family
   var $FontStyle;          // current font style
   var $underline;          // underlining flag
   var $CurrentFont;        // current font info
   var $FontSizePt;         // current font size in points
   var $FontSize;           // current font size in user unit
   var $DrawColor;          // commands for drawing color
   var $FillColor;          // commands for filling color
   var $TextColor;          // commands for text color
   var $ColorFlag;          // indicates whether fill and text colors are different
   var $ws;                 // word spacing
   var $images;             // array of used images
   var $PageLinks;          // array of links in pages
   var $links;              // array of internal links
   var $AutoPageBreak;      // automatic page breaking
   var $PageBreakTrigger;   // threshold used to trigger page breaks
   var $InHeader;           // flag set when processing header
   var $InFooter;           // flag set when processing footer
   var $ZoomMode;           // zoom display mode
   var $LayoutMode;         // layout display mode
   var $title;              // title
   var $subject;            // subject
   var $author;             // author
   var $keywords;           // keywords
   var $creator;            // creator
   var $AliasNbPages;       // alias for total number of pages
   var $PDFVersion;         // PDF version number

   /*******************************************************************************
   *                                                                              *
   *                               Public methods                                 *
   *                                                                              *
   *******************************************************************************/


   function __construct($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $size='A4')
   {
       // Some checks
       $this->_dochecks();
       // Initialization of properties
       $this->page = 0;
       $this->n = 2;
       $this->buffer = '';
       $this->pages = array();
       $this->PageSizes = array();
       $this->state = 0;
       $this->fonts = array();
       $this->FontFiles = array();
       $this->diffs = array();
       $this->images = array();
       $this->links = array();
       $this->InHeader = false;
       $this->InFooter = false;
       $this->lasth = 0;
       $this->FontFamily = '';
       $this->FontStyle = '';
       $this->FontSizePt = 12;
       $this->underline = false;
       $this->DrawColor = '0 G';
       $this->FillColor = '0 g';
       $this->TextColor = '0 g';
       $this->ColorFlag = false;
       $this->ws = 0;
       // Font path
       if(defined('FPDF_FONTPATH'))
       {
           $this->fontpath = FPDF_FONTPATH;
           if(substr($this->fontpath,-1)!='/' && substr($this->fontpath,-1)!='\\')
               $this->fontpath .= '/';
       }
       elseif(is_dir(dirname(__FILE__).'/font'))
           $this->fontpath = dirname(__FILE__).'/font/';
       else
           $this->fontpath = '';
       // Core fonts
       $this->CoreFonts = array('courier', 'helvetica', 'times', 'symbol', 'zapfdingbats');
       // Scale factor
       if($unit=='pt')
           $this->k = 1;
       elseif($unit=='mm')
           $this->k = 72/25.4;
       elseif($unit=='cm')
           $this->k = 72/2.54;
       elseif($unit=='in')
           $this->k = 72;
       else
           $this->Error('Incorrect unit: '.$unit);
       // Page sizes
       $this->StdPageSizes = array('a3'=>array(841.89,1190.55), 'a4'=>array(595.28,841.89), 'a5'=>array(420.94,595.28),
           'letter'=>array(612,792), 'legal'=>array(612,1008));
       $size = $this->_getpagesize($size);
       $this->DefPageSize = $size;
       $this->CurPageSize = $size;
       // Page orientation
       $orientation = mb_strtolower($orientation); // 20160707 ajout mb_
       if($orientation=='p' || $orientation=='portrait')
       {
           $this->DefOrientation = 'P';
           $this->w = $size[0];
           $this->h = $size[1];
       }
       elseif($orientation=='l' || $orientation=='landscape')
       {
           $this->DefOrientation = 'L';
           $this->w = $size[1];
           $this->h = $size[0];
       }
       else
           $this->Error('Incorrect orientation: '.$orientation);
       $this->CurOrientation = $this->DefOrientation;
       $this->wPt = $this->w*$this->k;
       $this->hPt = $this->h*$this->k;
       // Page margins (1 cm)
       $margin = 28.35/$this->k;
       $this->SetMargins($margin,$margin);
       // Interior cell margin (1 mm)
       $this->cMargin = $margin/10;
       // Line width (0.2 mm)
       $this->LineWidth = .567/$this->k;
       // Automatic page break
       $this->SetAutoPageBreak(true,2*$margin);
       // Default display mode
       $this->SetDisplayMode('default');
       // Enable compression
       $this->SetCompression(true);
       // Set default PDF version number
       $this->PDFVersion = '1.3';
   }

   //etc.

   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you're using TFPDF in combination with the PDF_MC_Table trait (see example 2 in Patrick's answer) and UTF-8 encoding, then you'll need to replace the original NbLines() function with this below. Basically it is a copy of the TFPDF MultiCell() function with the output lines removed.

```
public function NbLines($w,$txt) {
    $unifontSubset = property_exists($this, 'unifontSubset') && $this->unifontSubset;   # compatible with FPDF and TFPDF.

    // Output text with automatic or explicit line breaks
    if(!isset($this->CurrentFont))
        $this->Error('No font has been set');
    $cw = &$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    if($w==0)
        $w = $this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
    $wmax = ($w-2*$this->cMargin);
    //$wmax = ($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize;
    $s = str_replace("\r",'',(string)$txt);
    if ($unifontSubset) {
        $nb=mb_strlen($s, 'utf-8');
        while($nb>0 && mb_substr($s,$nb-1,1,'utf-8')=="\n") $nb--;
    }
    else {
        $nb = strlen($s);
        if($nb>0 && substr($s, $nb-1, 1) == "\n")
            $nb--;
    }
    $sep = -1;
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    $l = 0;
    $ns = 0;
    $nl = 1;
    while($i<$nb)
    {
        // Get next character
        if ($unifontSubset) {
            $c = mb_substr($s,$i,1,'UTF-8');
        }
        else {
            $c = substr($s,$i,1);
        }
        if($c=="\n")
        {
            $i++;
            $sep = -1;
            $j = $i;
            $l = 0;
            $ns = 0;
            $nl++;
            continue;
        }
        if($c==' ')
        {
            $sep = $i;
            $ls = $l;
            $ns++;
        }

        if ($unifontSubset) { $l += $this->GetStringWidth($c); }
        else { $l += $cw[$c]*$this->FontSize/1000; }

        if($l>$wmax)
        {
            // Automatic line break
            if($sep==-1)
            {
                if($i==$j)
                    $i++;
            }
            else
            {
                $i = $sep+1;
            }
            $sep = -1;
            $j = $i;
            $l = 0;
            $ns = 0;
            $nl++;
        }
        else
            $i++;
    }
    return $nl;
}
```